# How is Score Per Minute calculated in COD Warzone?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

I play the plunder game mode in COD Warzone.

In one game I played I got 13 kills and collected 1.3million, the majority of it from drops when I got kills. The score I got was 6393.

Another game I collected 750k and had 2 kills. The majority of cash came from loot boxes. My score was 5650.

I won both games.

Is there a way to find out how score is calculated in a game?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the exact formula but I can tell you Score is a combination of:

- downs/finishes/assists/damage
- reviving teammates
- buying stuff from buy stations
- picking up and completing contracts
- calling UAVs, Precisions and Clusters
- Using Munition and Armor boxes + teammates picking them up
- opening rare crates like the orange ones
- team wipes and special objectives like double and triple kills
- winning the match

so unless you keep all of these constant each game you will get a different score even if you kill 10 people and get the dub each game.

Comment: I’d like to add that the algorithm to calculate score could also check for details in each category; for example calling a UAV may be worth less than calling an air strike. There are just loads of potential variables here.